# Java Equivalent of curl query

Tags: android, httpclient, box-api

I am trying to fetch current user info after making him log into his box, using the box sdk for android. In the box api documentation, they have mentioned everything using curls. I am not familiar with curl. So, can anyone please  give me a java equivalent for this curl operation :

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN".
```

I have the users access token.So, please give me a java equivalent for the above curl operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java HttpClient

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"); // add headers if needded

//set params
BasicNameValuePair[] params = new BasicNameValuePair[] {new BasicNameValuePair("param1","param value"),
            new BasicNameValuePair("param2","param value")};

UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( Arrays.asList(params), "utf-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

//execute request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //here response in string you can parse it
```

Comment: what do i need to put for this line : -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" and how?. can you please tell the exact equivalent java code for the above curl code . i have the access token.but how to use it?

Comment: You should add it as header like that httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN");

Comment: i cant test your answer right away, bcoz i am away from my work computer.I will test it tomorrow and vote you up, if your answer helps.Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Pekar: But FYI, i have tried it the same way in hurl it, But it didnt work!

Comment: @Pekar: in hurl i got this reply "error="invalid_request", error_description="The access token was not found."" even though i sent a very valid access token.

Comment: Sorry you need to parse Www-Authenticate header to see why authorization information. Call response.getFirstHeader("Www-Authenticate") to get this header

Answer (score 0):

The HttpClient object that the other answer proposes is now deprecated. I solved a CURL problem like yours (with the extra difficulty of uploading a .wav file). Check out my code in this this answer/question. [How to upload a WAV file using URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089436/how-to-upload-a-wav-file-using-urlconnection)