# Java equivalent of curl post request with image and text

Tags: java, curl, http-post, mime-types

I'm trying to write java code to do exactly what this command does:

```
curl -F "image=@image.jpg" -F "param1=some-value" -F "param2=some_value" http://example.com
```

I'm currently trying something like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost poster = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
MultipartEntityBuilder mpEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
mpEntityBuilder.addPart("param1", new StringBody("some-value"));
mpEntityBuilder.addPart("param2", new StringBody("some-value"));
mpEntity.addPart("image", getImage("some-image"));
poster.setEntity(mpEntityBuilder .build());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(poster);
```

here getImage(String) returns a ByteArrayBody. (I'm actually downloading an image from the web on the fly rather than reading from disk like the curl command, but I don't think this should make a difference)

I checked out this link it but it doesn't exactly address the case where you're sending both an image as well as text parameters:
[Java Equivalent of curl query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388323/java-equivalent-of-curl-query)

What's strange is that I am using almost the same code to make an HTTP post to another API which works fine when I need to send an image alone without any textual parameters. (no stringbody)

But when I'm trying to send both an image(as a ByteArrayBody) and some text (as StringBody), I get a cryptic error message from the server that says something like:
'Could not initialize parameter object with mimeType: application/octet-stream'. It's probably a custom error message so I can't really find much information on this.

I tried using a few other constuctors for StringBody() since this one is deprecated, but it didn't help. Not sure what is the right constructor to use, but not sure if this would be causing a problem.

Edit: seems like someone's asked a very similar question before, but the solution does not work for me:
[Android: upload file with filling out POST body together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965022/android-upload-file-with-filling-out-post-body-together)
I get an error message about 
Failed parameter initialization with mimeType: application/octet-stream)

Comment: I believe that you'll need to Base64Encode the image. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416038/uploading-image-to-server-in-multipart-along-with-json-data-in-android

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. But it wouldn't explain why the code above works fine for doing what this curl command does:
curl -F "file"="@example.png" "https://example.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it documented but `curl -F @` apparently trying to be helpful **fills in `Content-type`** for some extensions/suffixes, including `image/jpeg` for `.jpg`. HttpClient does not, and defaults everything to the MIME 'I don't know' type `application/octet-stream` which presumably caused your error. **Use the 3-arg ctor** that sets the content-type

```
new ByteArrayBody (data, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), null)
```

or if you want to specify the filename attribute, which `curl -F @` also does but web servers (unlike browsers) *usually* don't care about, supply a `String` in place of the `null` third argument.

Comment: You're a genius! I'd given up after searching everywhere.